# postgress aurora export to s3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data from  Postgres aurora 11.7 Version to S3 using the aws s3 export csv comma delimited file from pgadmin . exports fine for some records after that I see first column data is jumbled. for example:

select * from aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('select "Flowers" from table_name  limit 1500000, 'test-bucket', 'flowers.csv', 'us-east-1', options:='FORMAT CSV, HEADER true');

This exports fine but when I query athena( select count(*),bu from table group by bu) with the s3 path I see two values
149999,Flower
1,FloweF -------you see how F is in the second  row when I do the group by.

what could I be doing wrong.

1. There are no two files.
2. I deleted files in s3 and recreated.